# How avoid style inheritance

Tags: jquery, html, css

Am using Jquery. Every page am having tables.For table I have some default style for a particular page. Every tr am having another child table. Child tables I do not need parent table style informations. How to prevent child table from parent table style inheritance property.Please help If you have any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One ugly way is to use `!important`. But with proper design and use of selectors, you could do this easily.

Comment: where is the code sangeetha??

Comment: Is this question about CSS or jQuery?

Comment: The whole idea of CSS is that it cascades, so the descendants must override.

Comment: If you need different styles of table, nested, I would suggest you decorate the various tables with classes appropriate to the style of table you want and not just depend on CSS nesting rules (which are not supported the same across all browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the direct child selector to separate the tables:

```
.someContainer > table{ /* This would match the parent tables */ }
table table { /* This will match tables within a table */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [not operator](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('table').not('table table').css('background-color','red');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tztvp/)

---

If you want to perform this only with css then you could do:

```
table{
   /*parent table style here*/
}
table table{
   /*child table style here*/
}
```

Comment: This is a styling issue (should have been tagged with CSS and not JQuery). *It is also incorrect anyway* as the selector you used has single-quotes within single-quotess.

Comment: Better and would work now (have removed my -1), but it appears they want a CSS solution (although the question is not clear).

Comment: The OP was tagged jquery not css!

Comment: You expected a newbie to get the tags right? :) It now has all sorts of tags.

Comment: um! yeah. it depends on OP.